# transform object member type depending on the original type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

In an object, I want to transform each member's type to another depending on the said member variable.

Here is an exemple:

```js
class A {
    fct = (): string => 'blabla';
}

class B {
    fct = (): number => 1;
}

class C {
    fct = (): { obj: string } => ({
        obj: 'la'
    });
}

export const Contracts = {
    a: A,
    b: B,
    c: C
};

type myContracts = typeof Contracts;

type MySuperType<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: string;
};

type a = MySuperType<myContracts>;
```

The snipped above gives:

```
type a = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
```

What I want:

```
type a = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: { obj: string };
}
```

Comment: Use a constraint and InstanceType: https://tsplay.dev/wRBJLw

Comment: @vera. make this the answer, i'll upvote and mark it as is

Comment: Also, how did you learn all of that ? It's such a headache for me. Any tips/recommendation ? I'm really good at ts but this whole typings rabbit whole is still new to me

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75392116/transform-object-member-type-depending-on-the-original-type#comment133028622_75392116) @sshmaxime Read the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) and release notes

Comment: i thought i was good at typescript too... then i found out about type challenge (https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `MySuperType` require that the values on the object satisfy a class whose instances have a `fct` property that's a function. Take the `InstanceType` of the class to get the instance, then use `ReturnType` to get the returned type for each such instance.

```
type FctClass = {
  new(): { fct: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown}
}
type MySuperType<T extends Record<string, FctClass>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<InstanceType<T[P]>['fct']>;
};

type a = MySuperType<myContracts>;
```